# LibGDX - How do I prevent a sound from playing too loud when overlapping?

Tags: audio, libgdx, volume

I'm having an issue with sound volume in the game I'm building.

One example would be when I fire a rocket its explosion creates a blast radius, and any enemies in the radius get killed.

When one enemy is killed at a time the volume level for the death sound (a little scream) is perfect, but when 3 or 4 get killed in one blast the sound plays 4 times as loud.

I've thought about looking into adding a check to see if the sound is already being played and only playing if not, but decided against that because if one enemy is killed half a second after another only one scream would play.

What I'd like is for additional overlapping instances of a sound to all play at the same volume instead of adding to the overall volume.

What's the right way to go about implementing that?

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76312/how-to-prevent-overlapping-of-gunshot-sounds-when-using-fast-firing-weapons or even or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60939/how-to-prevent-multiple-playing-sounds-from-destroying-your-hearing  (not really libgdx specific)

Comment: Thanks P.T. - neither of those links had a precise solution that was feasible for my issue, but the combination of the two of them got me thinking along the right track to come up with a working solution :)

Answer (score 3):

The links provided in P.T.'s comment got me thinking along the lines of limiting concurrent plays for any given sound.

The solution I devised turned out to be blindingly simple: whenever a sound that can overlap is triggered, I simply stop that sound before it plays.

Instead of:

```
if (prefs.isSoundEnabled())
    sndExplosion.play();
```

I simply expanded it to:

```
if (prefs.isSoundEnabled()) {
    sndExplosion.stop();
    sndExplosion.play();
}
```

The result is that if there's already an explosion being played or if multiple explosions are triggered at the same time, only one copy of the sound gets played at once.